# Combining multiple RNNs in keras

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have 2 (independently long) sequences (a and b) of feature vectors that I want to use as input for a neural network.
The idea was to build 2 GRU based encoders (one for each sequence).
I would than have a decoder (that takes the 2 encoded states) to produce the final output (a number).

My training data would be something like

```
([a11, a11, a12], [b11, b12, b13]) => v1
([a21, a21], [b21, b22, b23, b24]) => v2
([a31], [b31, b32]) => v3
```

Where axy (and bxy) are feature vectors. vx is the output value (a float) of the neural network.

```
    # lenA maximum length of a sequence
    # lenB maximum length of b sequence
    # featuresA number of features for a
    # featuresB number of features for b

    enc1InputData=np.zeros((count, lenA, featuresA))
    enc2InputData=np.zeros((count, lenB, featuresB))
    decoderInputData=np.zeros((count, 1, 1))
    decoderOutputData=np.zeros((count, 1))

    # Initialize input data
    ... 

    enc1Input = Input(shape=(None, featuresA))
    enc1 = GRU(256, return_state=True)
    enc1Output, enc1State = enc1(enc1Input)

    enc2Input = Input(shape=(None, featuresB))
    enc2 = GRU(256, return_state=True)
    enc2Output, enc2State = enc2(enc2Input)

    encOutput=concatenate([enc1State, enc2State])

    decoderInput = Input(shape=(None, 1))
    decoderGru = GRU(256+256, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
    decoderOutput, _ = decoderGru(decoderInput, initial_state=encOutput)

    for i in range(3):
        decoderDense=Dense(parms.dim3, activation="relu")
        decoderOutput = decoderDense(decoderOutput)

    #flatten = Flatten()
    #decoderOutput=flatten(decoderOutput)

    decoderTanh = Dense(1, activation="tanh")
    decoderOutput = decoderTanh(decoderOutput)

    model=Model([enc1Input, enc2Input, decoderInput], decoderOutput)
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")

    model.fit([enc1InputData, enc2InputData, decoderInputData], decoderOutputData, batch_size=256, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2)
```

This gives me a

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1)
```

Including the Flatten step gives a

```
ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, 256)). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following GRU layer expects an input of shape `(None, 1)` (not including the batch size) and outputs a tensor of shape `(None, 512)` (i.e. a *sequence* of 512 dimensional vectors) because `return_sequences=True`, if you set it to `False`, the output is of shape `(512,)` (i.e. just a single vector not a sequence).

```
decoderInput = Input(shape=(None, 1))
decoderGru = GRU(256+256, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
```

Thus, having `return_sequences=True` means that the following `Dense` layer also accepts a sequence of 512 dimensional vectors, i.e. `(None, 512)` and returns a tensor of shape `(None, dense_units)` where `dense_units` is the number of hidden units of this `Dense` layer. However your training output is of shape `(1,)`.

So, I think `return_sequences=True` is not exactly what you're trying to do. Setting it `False` should resolve the problem.

Comment: Your change removes the error messages. But the training is not working. I only get loss: nan (and val_loss: nan)

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck Getting NaN as loss usually means that there's something wrong with your input data, maybe they're too large and not normalized.

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck Also a large batch size can result in this problem, please try with a smaller batch size.

Comment: You were right again. There were nan's in the input data